# What does "setting" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> There is a lot of information in this video, much more than anyone can digest **in one single setting**.

It seems like "one single time" or something like that, I suppose. But I can't find a similar explanation in any dictionaries.

As it is easy to be confused, I put the link to the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AT2hFlpS4dQ).
The sentence is at 13:25 and It's indeed a "**setting**" but not a "**sitting**".

Comment: Please provide more context?  Did you hear this somewhere, or did you read it?  Are you sure it's "setting" and not "sitting"?

Comment: @Andrew Video link added. :)

Comment: Ah.  Got it now.  In this case "setting" refers to this particular *episode*, as in one single video.   All of these guidelines have been delivered to you as a big *set* of information.  It's an odd phrasing -- but if you hadn't pointed it out, I wouldn't have thought anything of it.

Comment: @Andrew Now I've understood the phrase and more importantly I will not use it by myself since it's an odd phrasing. This kind of question must be answered by a native speaker like you. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It might just be a simple spelling error in your transcript or whatever it is that you've got there. They might have misspelled the word [**sitting**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sitting) as *setting*. Or you might have misheard it as *setting* if it was you who were writing that transcript. Anyway, *sitting* makes more sense and is actually the word you would more likely see used in this context. And if that's the case, it's now all down to a simple dictionary lookup:

> ## sitting
>
> A continuous period of being seated, especially when engaged in a particular activity.
>
> ---
>
> 'twenty pieces of music is a bit much to take in **at one sitting**'
>
> 'And sure, it is a lot to ask the average museum visitor to sit through eight films **in one sitting**.'
>
> 'The more calories you eat **in a sitting**, the more likely you are to store them as body fat.'

Comment: Like my answer says, is it possible they were referring to one table "setting" so essentially one meal? That's the only way I can make sense of it.

Comment: If it's not a spelling problem, then I totally agree with you.

Comment: Yeah it's possible that it's a spelling error like you said. I almost always hear people say one **sitting**

Comment: Video link added. You could have a look at the video. :)